# varying header elements that are yield in the layout folder in rails 4.2.4

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

I am newish to programming and building my first e-commerce web application using rails 4.2.4

I have a price container in the header of my application.html.erb which yields across the show.html.erb and index.html.erb pages.

Issue: I only want the price container to yield on the show page (NOT the index).

I have tried deleting the `<% content_for :head do %>`on the index page but the price container remains on this specific page.

I would be grateful for some steering. Screenshots and code below.

[image: show.html.erb]
[image: index.html.erb]

> My application.html.erb page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>  
  <title>One Month Growth Hacking</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700,300,800">

  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => false %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => false %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content" class="container">
        <header id="content-header">
            <div id="price-container">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tag"></span><span class="price">$4.99</span>
            </div>
            <%= yield :head %>
        </header>

        <%= yield %>

</div>
```

> My index.html.erb page

```
<% content_for :head do %>
  <%= image_tag('skincare.png', id: 'content-header-img', alt: 'check out our products') %>
<% end %>   

<section id="article-title" class="row clearfix">
    <article id="details-article">
        <h1 id="article-title">Nippon Beauty Products</h1>
    </article>
</section>

<section id="products">
<% @products.each do |product| %>
     <div class="product clearfix">
       <a href="<%=product_path(product) %>"</a>
        <div class="product-image-container">
         <img src="<%= asset_path product.thumbnail_image_name %>" alt="<%= product.title %>"/>
         <span class="product-price">$<%= product.price %></span>
        </div>
       <p class="product-title"><%= product.title %></p></a>
     </div>
<% end %>

 </section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you remove this from your application.html.erb

```
<div id="price-container">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tag"></span><span class="price">$4.99</span>
</div>
```

And then in your show.html.erb file you add it in your content for :head before the image tag

```
<% content_for :head do %>
  -> put it here <-
  <%= image_tag('skincare.png', id: 'content-header-img', alt: 'check out our products') %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: in the put it here section, are you saying to code the div id price container with the span class

Comment: Yes i mean that you have to put that there

Comment: will try and revert back shortly

Comment: robbert that works absolutely superb. thank you very much for your steering sir, really appreciate that

Answer (score 0):

You can check if `:head` has been defined and only `yield` if it has:

```
<% if content_for?(:head) %>
  <%= yield(:head) %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: thank you for the help. Has your code to go into the index.html.erb